# Wamp: Apache variable "${INSTALL_DIR}" is not defined

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I just used the file from [Here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) to upgrade my Wamp Server to PHP 7.2.9. After I install and enable PHP 7.2.9, I look at php_error.log and I see `Apache variable "${INSTALL_DIR}" is not defined.`

How do I fix this problem? I am using Apache 2.4.9 and MySQL 5.6.17

Comment: Operating system ? also can you show your apache config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare 'INSTALL_DIR' inside wamp\bin\apache\apache[ your version ]\conf\httpd.conf

Define INSTALL_DIR c:/wamp [ or your wamp path ]